# Comparing data dates with 5 days ago in multiple files

Tags: shell, date

I have dates(like 20230315) at first column and some data at second and third columns in 17030.dat 17130.dat and some .dat files. I want to compare last line of date with five days ago date. If five days ago date less than the last line of date in files then ok else which files are they i want to find out them.

files contents

```
10082020    28.23    31.10
11082020    28.56    32.00
12082020    26.89    28.10
13082020    26.05    29.10
```

```
#!/bin/bash
now=$(date "+%Y%m%d")
fivedaysago=$(date -d "$now -5 days" +%Y%m%d )

for i in /home/celaleddin/17*
do
while read line; do
date= tail -n 1 | awk '{print $1}'
if [ $fivedaysago -lt $date ];then
echo "ok"
else
echo $filename
fi

done < $i
done
```

I couldn't compare them successfully.
Expected outputs are files that if last line of date in files smaller than five days ago date

Comment: Always first test your script to https://shellcheck.net before asking here. Thanks

Comment: Please show use sample input & expected output in a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: *" Expected outputs are files that  ..."*  Sorry, verbal descriptions of expected out don't really help readers not sitting next to you. Please inlclude a small set of testable data and the expected output from that same data. Also the exact text of error messages. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU AWK

```
awk '
    BEGIN{
        "date --date=\"5 day ago\" +%Y%m%d" | getline fivedaysago
    }
    NF==3 && match($1,/^[0-9]{8}$/){
        arr[FILENAME] = $1
    }
    END{
        for (filename in arr){
            lastdate=gensub(/([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})/,"\\3\\2\\1",1,arr[filename])
            if (fivedaysago < lastdate){ 
                print "ok"
            }else{
                print filename
            }
        }
    }
' /home/celaleddin/17*.dat
```

---

Your Solution (corrected):

```
#!/bin/bash

now="$(date "+%Y%m%d")"
fivedaysago="$(date -d "$now -5 days" +%Y%m%d)"
for file in /home/celaleddin/17*.dat
do
    date=$(tail -n 1 "$file" | awk '{print $1}')
    date="${date:4:4}${date:2:2}${date:0:2}"  
    if [[ "$fivedaysago" < "$date" ]];then
        echo "ok"
    else
        echo "$file"
    fi
done
```